# unwanted type conversion in pandas.DataFrame.update

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any reason why pandas changes the type of columns from int to float in update, and can I prevent it from doing it? Here is some example code of the problem

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'int': [1, 2], 'float': [np.nan, np.nan]})

print('Integer column:')
print(df['int'])

for _, df_sub in df.groupby('int'):
    df_sub['float'] = float(df_sub['int'])
    df.update(df_sub)

print('NO integer column:')
print(df['int'])
```

Comment: this a bug (a bit non-trivial to fix though): https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4094

Comment: you can of course always ``df['int'].astype(int)``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here's the reason for this: since you are effectively masking certain values on a column and replace them (with your updates), some values could become `` `nan ``

in an integer array this is impossible, so numeric dtypes are apriori converted to float (for efficiency), as checking first is more expensive that doing this

a change of dtype back is possible...just not in the code right now, therefor this a bug (a bit non-trivial to fix though): github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4094

Answer (score 0):

This causes data precision loss if you have big values in your int64 column, when update converts them to float. So going back with what Jeff suggests: `df['int'].astype(int)`
is not always possible.

My workaround for cases like this is:

```
df_sub['int'] = df_sub['int'].astype('Int64')  # Int64 with capital I, supports NA values
df.update(df_sub)
df_sub['int'] = df_sub['int'].astype('int')
```

The above avoids the conversion to float type. The reason I am converting back to int type (instead of leaving it as Int64) is that pandas seems to lack support for that type in several operations (e.g. concat gives an error about missing .view).

Maybe they could incorporate the above fix in [issue 4094](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4094)