# pandas left join and update existing column

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and can't seem to get this to work with merge function:

```
>>> left       >>> right
   a  b   c       a  c   d 
0  1  4   9    0  1  7  13
1  2  5  10    1  2  8  14
2  3  6  11    2  3  9  15
3  4  7  12
```

With a left join on column a, I would like to update common columns BY THE JOINED KEYS. Note last value in column c is from LEFT table since there is no match.

```
>>> final       
   a  b   c   d 
0  1  4   7   13
1  2  5   8   14
2  3  6   9   15
3  4  7   12  NAN
```

How should I do this with Pandas merge function? Thank you.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One way to do this is to set the a column as the index and [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
In [11]: left_a = left.set_index('a')

In [12]: right_a = right.set_index('a')
```

*Note: `update` only does a left join (not merges), so as well as set_index you also need to include the additional columns not present in `left_a`.*

```
In [13]: res = left_a.reindex(columns=left_a.columns.union(right_a.columns))

In [14]: res.update(right_a)

In [15]: res.reset_index(inplace=True)

In [16]: res
Out[16]:
   a   b   c   d
0  1   4   7  13
1  2   5   8  14
2  3   6   9  15
3  4   7  12 NaN
```

Comment: Warning for those of you implementing this solution: In certain conditions integer dtypes are changed to float! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398216/unwanted-type-conversion-in-pandas-dataframe-update

Comment: Warning: Using `loc` for adding new columns is deprecated. Use `reindex` like this `left_a.reindex(columns=left_a.columns.union(right_a.columns))` instead.

Comment: Your welcome. You gave me the answer I needed and built on top of ;)

Comment: Warning: per the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), `DataFrame.update()` will not overwrite non nan values with nan values.

Answer (score 57):

You can use `merge()` between `left` and `right` with `how='left'` on `'a'` column.

```
In [74]: final = left.merge(right, on='a', how='left')

In [75]: final
Out[75]:
   a  b  c_x  c_y   d
0  1  4    9    7  13
1  2  5   10    8  14
2  3  6   11    9  15
3  4  7   12  NaN NaN
```

Replace `NaN` value from `c_y` with `c_x` value

```
In [76]: final['c'] = final['c_y'].fillna(final['c_x'])

In [77]: final
Out[77]:
   a  b  c_x  c_y   d   c
0  1  4    9    7  13   7
1  2  5   10    8  14   8
2  3  6   11    9  15   9
3  4  7   12  NaN NaN  12
```

Drop unwanted columns, and you have the result

```
In [79]: final.drop(['c_x', 'c_y'], axis=1)
Out[79]:
   a  b   d   c
0  1  4  13   7
1  2  5  14   8
2  3  6  15   9
3  4  7 NaN  12
```

Comment: That fillna(with a different column) is pretty neat!

Comment: I like this method better than the accepted answer because it doesn't depend on the two DataFrames having a join key variable ('a' in this example) in common.

Comment: I consistently get this error when I use this code:
FutureWarning: Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative. My only thought is that my dfs may not share the same columns? Isn't that what the original answer was supposed to correct for though?

Comment: This answer is the most pythonic way of doing it

Answer (score 2):

[DataFrame.update()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) is nice, but it doesn't let you specify columns to join on and more importantly, if the *other* dataframe has NaN values, those NaN values will not overwrite non-nan values in the original DataFrame. To me, this is undesirable behavior.

Here's a custom method I rolled to fix these issues. It's freshly written, so users beware..

## join_insertion()

```
def join_insertion(into_df, from_df, cols, on, by=None, direction=None, mult='error'):
    """
    Suppose A and B are dataframes. A has columns {foo, bar, baz} and B has columns {foo, baz, buz}
    This function allows you to do an operation like:
    "where A and B match via the column foo, insert the values of baz and buz from B into A"
    Note that this'll update A's values for baz and it'll insert buz as a new column.
    This is a lot like DataFrame.update(), but that method annoyingly ignores NaN values in B!

    Optionally, direction can be given as 'backward', 'forward', or nearest to implement a rolling join
    insertion. forward means 'roll into_df values forward to match from_df values', etc. Additionally,
    when doing a rolling join, 'on' should be the roll column and 'by' should be the exact-match columns.
    See pandas.merge_asof() for details.

    Note that 'mult' gets ignored when doing a rolling join. In the case of a rolling join, the first
    appearing record is kept, even if two records match a key from the same distance. Perhaps this
    can be improved...

    :param into_df: dataframe you want to modify
    :param from_df: dataframe with the values you want to insert
    :param cols: list of column names (values to insert)
    :param on: list of column names (values to join on), or a dict of {into:from} column name pairs
    :param by: same format as on; when doing a rolling join insertion, what columns to exact-match on
    :param direction: 'forward', 'backward', or 'nearest'. forward means roll into_df values to match from_df
    :param mult: if a key of into_df matches multiple rows of from_df, how should this be handled?
    an error can be raised, or the first matching value can be inserted, or the last matching value
    can be inserted
    :return: a modified copy of into_df, with updated values using from_df
    """

    # Infer left_on, right_on
    if (isinstance(on, dict)):
        left_on = list(on.keys())
        right_on = list(on.values())
    elif(isinstance(on, list)):
        left_on = on
        right_on = on
    elif(isinstance(on, str)):
        left_on = [on]
        right_on = [on]
    else:
        raise Exception("on should be a list or dictionary")

    # Infer left_by, right_by
    if(by is not None):
        if (isinstance(by, dict)):
            left_by = list(by.keys())
            right_by = list(by.values())
        elif (isinstance(by, list)):
            left_by = by
            right_by = by
        elif (isinstance(by, str)):
            left_by = [by]
            right_by = [by]
        else:
            raise Exception("by should be a list or dictionary")
    else:
        left_by = None
        right_by = None

    # Make cols a list if it isn't already
    if(isinstance(cols, str)):
        cols = [cols]

    # Setup
    A = into_df.copy()
    B = from_df[right_on + cols + ([] if right_by is None else right_by)].copy()

    # Insert row ids
    A['_A_RowId_'] = np.arange(A.shape[0])
    B['_B_RowId_'] = np.arange(B.shape[0])

    # Merge
    if(direction is None):
        A = pd.merge(
            left=A,
            right=B,
            how='left',
            left_on=left_on,
            right_on=right_on,
            suffixes=(None, '_y'),
            indicator=True
        ).sort_values(['_A_RowId_', '_B_RowId_'])

        # Check for rows of A which got duplicated by the merge, and then handle appropriately
        if (mult == 'error'):
            if (A.groupby('_A_RowId_').size().max() > 1):
                raise Exception("At least one key of into_df matched multiple rows of from_df.")
        elif (mult == 'first'):
            A = A.groupby('_A_RowId_').first().reset_index()
        elif (mult == 'last'):
            A = A.groupby('_A_RowId_').last().reset_index()

    else:
        A.sort_values(left_on, inplace=True)
        B.sort_values(right_on, inplace=True)
        A = pd.merge_asof(
            left=A,
            right=B,
            direction=direction,
            left_on=left_on,
            right_on=right_on,
            left_by=left_by,
            right_by=right_by,
            suffixes=(None, '_y')
        ).sort_values(['_A_RowId_', '_B_RowId_'])

    # Insert values from new column(s) into pre-existing column(s)
    mask = A._merge == 'both' if direction is None else np.repeat(True, A.shape[0])
    cols_in_both = list(set(into_df.columns.to_list()).intersection(set(cols)))
    for col in cols_in_both:
        A.loc[mask, col] = A.loc[mask, col + '_y']

    # Drop unwanted columns
    A.drop(columns=list(set(A.columns).difference(set(into_df.columns.to_list() + cols))), inplace=True)

    return A
```

## Example Use

```
into_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'foo': [1, 2, 3],
    'bar': [4, 5, 6],
    'baz': [7, 8, 9]
})
   foo  bar  baz
0    1    4    7
1    2    5    8
2    3    6    9

from_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'foo': [1, 3, 5, 7, 3],
    'baz': [70, 80, 90, 30, 40],
    'buz': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
})
   foo  baz  buz
0    1   70    0
1    3   80    1
2    5   90    2
3    7   30    3
4    3   40    4

# Use it!

join_insertion(into_df, from_df, on='foo', cols=['baz','buz'], mult='error')
  Exception: At least one key of into_df matched multiple rows of from_df.

join_insertion(into_df, from_df, on='foo', cols=['baz','buz'], mult='first')
   foo  bar   baz  buz
0    1    4  70.0  0.0
1    2    5   8.0  NaN
2    3    6  80.0  1.0

join_insertion(into_df, from_df, on='foo', cols=['baz','buz'], mult='last')
   foo  bar   baz  buz
0    1    4  70.0  0.0
1    2    5   8.0  NaN
2    3    6  40.0  4.0
```

As an aside, this is one of those things I severely miss from R's data.table package. With data.table, this is as easy as `x[y, Foo := i.Foo, on = c("a", "b")]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with `join`:

```
In [632]: t = left.set_index('a').join(right.set_index('a'), rsuffix='_right')

In [633]: t
Out[633]: 
   b   c  c_right   d
a                    
1  4   9        7  13
2  5  10        8  14
3  6  11        9  15
4  7  12      NaN NaN
```

Now, we want to set null values of `c_right` (which is from the `right` dataframe) with values from `c` column from the `left` dataframe. Updated the below process with a method taking from @John Galt's answer

```
In [657]: t['c_right'] = t['c_right'].fillna(t['c'])

In [658]: t
Out[658]: 
   b   c  c_right   d
a                    
1  4   9        7  13
2  5  10        8  14
3  6  11        9  15
4  7  12       12 NaN

In [659]: t.drop('c_right', axis=1)
Out[659]: 
   b   c   d
a           
1  4   9  13
2  5  10  14
3  6  11  15
4  7  12 NaN
```

Comment: Something is strange because you're updating `t['c_right']` but then dropping it.  I think you want `t['c'] = t['c_right'].fillna(t['c'])` and then drop `t['c_right']`.

Answer (score 1):

One other way is to use [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.merge.html) like so:

```
 >>> import pandas as pd

 >>> final = pd.merge(left=right, right=left, 
                      how='outer',
                      left_index=True,
                      right_index=True,
                      on=('a', 'c')
                     ).sort_index(axis=1)

 >>> final       
    a  b   c   d 
 0  1  4   7   13.0
 1  2  5   8   14.0
 2  3  6   9   15.0
 3  4  7   12  NaN
```

Provide the intersection of both dataframe's columns to the 'on=' parameter of the function.

This does not create unwanted columns that have to be dropped like with Zero's solution.

The NaN value might change integers to floats in the same column.

Edit: This works for Pandas versions <= 1.1.5

Comment: Hey, your solution is the only one that worked for me where I have thousands of column. It saved my day and perhaps my life too. Thank you.

Comment: Question, why `on=('a', 'c')`?

Comment: @MarceloGazzola 'a' because the values of the columns of the left and the right frames are the same. Merging them will remove one of them. 'c' because OP wanted the rows of the left frame to be updated with the values of the 'c' columns of the right frame. No need to add 'b' and 'd' because they dont exist in both frames.

Answer (score -2):

Here is another way that should work using `combine_first()`

```
right.set_index('a').combine_first(left.set_index('a')).reset_index()
```