# Python pandas join dataframes on unordered index failing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have two Pandas dataframes read from csv files that I want to join. Both have an ID column that I set as index. Then I simply join them based on the index.
Unfortunately when I do this and the index of the second df does not follow the same order of the first df it fails.
E.g.:

```
>>> print df1
                A     B
ID                                                                         
004583404.1_1   CYT   NaN
005874764.1_2   CYT   NaN
004583406.1_3   TMH   NaN
005873538.1_36  SpII  cleavage=18-19
005873971.1_57  SpII  cleavage=18-19

>>> print df2
                LipoBoxSimilarity OM/IM  Cleavage site
Sequence name                                        
005873971.1_57              High    OM             19
005873538.1_36              High    OM             19

>>> print df1.join(df2)
                A     B     LipoBoxSimilarity OM/IM  Cleavage site
ID                                                                         
004583404.1_1   CYT   NaN                 NaN   NaN            NaN
005874764.1_2   CYT   NaN                 NaN   NaN            NaN
004583406.1_3   TMH   NaN                 NaN   NaN            NaN
005873538.1_36  SpII  cleavage=18-19     High    OM             19
005873971.1_57  SpII  cleavage=18-19     High    OM             19
```

When I merge those two df it still works. Then, when I use the actual file as input (with just more rows) it does not work anymore.
The two df separately are built correctly and indexes appropriate, columns also merges, but not values. So I end up in this situation:

```
>>> print df1.join(df2)
                A     B     LipoBoxSimilarity OM/IM  Cleavage site
ID                                                                         
004583404.1_1   CYT   NaN                 NaN   NaN            NaN
005874764.1_2   CYT   NaN                 NaN   NaN            NaN
004583406.1_3   TMH   NaN                 NaN   NaN            NaN
005873538.1_36  SpII  cleavage=18-19      NaN   NaN            NaN
005873971.1_57  SpII  cleavage=18-19      NaN   NaN            NaN
```

What could possibly the cause? I could not find any issue in the docs related the index order. Would be an alphanumerical index a problem maybe (e.g. WP_004583404.1_1)? I tried of course also merging based on column (so without setting them as index), but it also does not work.

Comment: check this answer, `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045086/pandas-left-join-and-update-existing-column`

Comment: The problem was in one of the file. Since ID is a string/object they have to match perfectly, but there was a space at the end of each value of the column 'ID', thus indexes were actually different. A simple `df1.join(df2)` works. I think I should delete the question, since it was sort of " wrong" .

Answer (score 0):

Try [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html). Note I have already aligned common column name ('ID') between the 2 dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import *

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A': {0: 'CYT', 1: 'CYT', 2: 'TMH', 3: 'SpII', 4: 'SpII'},
                              'B': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: 'cleavage=18-19', 4: 'cleavage=18-19'},
                              'ID': {0: '004583404.1_1',
                                     1: '005874764.1_2',
                                     2: '004583406.1_3',
                                     3: '005873538.1_36',
                                     4: '005873971.1_57'}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Cleavage site': {0: 19, 1: 19},
                              'LipoBoxSimilarity': {0: 'High', 1: 'High'},
                              'OM/IM': {0: 'OM', 1: 'OM'},
                              'ID': {0: '005873971.1_57', 1: '005873538.1_36'}})

df1.combine_first(df2)

#       A               B  Cleavage site              ID LipoBoxSimilarity OM/IM
# 0   CYT             NaN           19.0   004583404.1_1              High    OM
# 1   CYT             NaN           19.0   005874764.1_2              High    OM
# 2   TMH             NaN            NaN   004583406.1_3               NaN   NaN
# 3  SpII  cleavage=18-19            NaN  005873538.1_36               NaN   NaN
# 4  SpII  cleavage=18-19            NaN  005873971.1_57               NaN   NaN
```