# Replacing NaN of a dataframe based on the values of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Chaps, I'm one those who just started learning Python and pandas. So I have got two dataframes, lets call them **df1** and **df2**. And I need to replace NaN rows in column 'modernized' of df1 with those in 'modernized' of df2. I tried the method below, but it seems like not working, so could you help me?
I would have tried logical indexing but, the rows that must be replaced (in df1) are about 300 and I need something that could do it without calling and going through each of those 300 rows. Below is the df1 and df2.

my method:

```
for platform in df['platform'].dropna().unique():
   df1.loc[(df1['platform'] == platform) & (df1['released'].isna()), 'released2'] = \
                       2.loc[df2.loc['platform'] == platform, 'released'].values[0]



df1 = pd.DataFrame(
{"name": ['FX4', 'TR55', 'KL55', 'MS-KL', 'UU-KL'],
 "impedance": [-44, 55, 4, 4, 8],
 "modernized": [pd.Timestamp("2020-01-23"), 
                pd.Timestamp("2020-04-25"),
                pd.NaT, 
                pd.NaT, 
                pd.NaT]
}
)

   df2 = pd.DataFrame({
                       "name": [ 'KL55', 'MS-KL', 'UU-KL'],
                       "modernized": [pd.Timestamp("2020-04-20"),  
                                      pd.Timestamp("2020-04-25"),
                                      pd.Timestamp("2020-08-23")]
                      })
```

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045086/pandas-left-join-and-update-existing-column