# update a Dataframe from a different Dataframe based on a matching value

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, DF1(33, 92) and DF2(11, 18) , I want to copy the DF2 18 columns to DF1 based on a matching value from a column name 'ID' in both DFs, these 18 columns have the same names in both dataframes.

I used the following merge: `finaldf = pd.merge(DF1, DF2, on = 'ID', how ='left')`

This works fine except it changed the 18 columns names in the DF1 and added another 18 columns. so the final dataframe shape was (33, 109) while it supposes to have DF1 shape (33, 92) but with an updated rows.

Comment: If "ID" is "index" column in  DF1 then we cant achieve this requirement, as we cant have 2 rows with same index ID.

Comment: Look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for pandas merge. Merge method will add suffixes if there are same column names in both dfs, to distinguish between them. You can later rename/remove the extra ones.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas left join and update existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045086/pandas-left-join-and-update-existing-column)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your  `finaldf` after merge has shape (33, 109) because it has columns with similar names but `_x` and `_y` appended to them. `_x` ones are from **DF1** and `_y` ones are from **DF2**.

You need to run the below code after merge to remove the extra "_x" and "_y" columns for those 18 and copy the values from **DF2** to **DF1** where they matched on "ID":

```
remove_cols = []

for col in DF2.columns:
    if col == 'ID':
        continue
    finaldf[col] = finaldf[col+'_y'].fillna(finaldf[col+'_x'])
    remove_cols += [col+'_x', col+'_y']

finaldf.drop(remove_cols, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

---

For more information on why "_x" and "_y" columns appear in your merged dataframe, I would recommend you to check the official [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) of `pd.DataFrame.merge`  method once.
"_x" and "_y" are suffixes that **merge** operation adds by default to distinguish between columns with similar names.

**Alternatively:**

`pd.DataFrame.update` is a method in pandas to achieve what you are trying to do.

Check it out [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html). But there is one caveat with using it, which is that if you have **NaN** values in DF2 that you would like to copy to DF1, then it won't do that. It will update only `non-NA` values:

> Modify in place using non-NA values from another DataFrame.

Comment: thanks for your detailed reply, I will give it a shot, but does it help if I change 18 columns names in DF2 and map them to the corresponding 18 columns in DF1 to avoid duplicates names ? if so. does the below line work. finaldf = pd.merge(DF1[cols_18], DF2, on = 'ID', how ='left')

Comment: the 18 column names in DF1 and DF2 are already same right?  Thats why '_x' and '_y' are getting added by merge.

Comment: thanks, right, what if I change DF2 columns names, how I would map them back to the DF1 while they`re having different columns names? does it work like that ?

Comment: No, then that's a completely diffrerent scenario. `pd.merge` will not help you in that case, and there will a lot else that will need to be done. This answer and the other one only cover the case that you posted in your question. Changes to original scenario will obviously require changes in approach.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, I`m testing out why there are few extra rows while it supposes to not add any. my question for the moment about your python code, what would you do to make the loop skip a populated data within 18 columns of _x after merging?

Comment: hopefully to hear from you regarding the python lines, appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi, sorry I was inactive. I didn't understand your question "skip a populated data within 18 columns of _x after merging". If you have some new requirement, scenario that you would like to cover, you can always post a new question. That way you will be able to explain your use-case better. And let me know if you post it, will help you out :)

Comment: my use case is so detailed within your reply of python code, I appreciate if you follow up with me here as you already gave me a detailed answer and I`m following upon your reply of python code

Comment: finaldf[col] = finaldf[col+'_y'].fillna(finaldf[col+'_x']) , I want to add a condition to your pytong code that if there is a filled cell in finaldf[col] not to copy anything from finaldf[col+'_y']. how to add the conditional copy if statement within your code.

Comment: There is no `finaldf[col]` already in your df after merge. This loop is actually creating it. After merge you have `finaldf[col+'_x']` and `finaldf[col+'_y']`. Now `pd.merge` already took care of copying values from DF2 to DF1 matching on ID. These are stored in `finaldf[col+'_y']`. Where they did not match, you wanted to keep DF1's values right. That's what this python line is doing in loop. And in that process, since you do not want '_x' and '_y' columns in `finaldf`, I basically created `finaldf['col']` to store final data. It was not in your merged `finaldf` that you can put condition on.

Comment: seems the new scenario doesnt required merging , how I would notify you if I post a new question?

Answer (score 0):

if you want the values for those 18 columns (say col1,col2...col18) from DF2 only, you can do

```
cols_18 = ["col1",col2"....]
cols_to_use = list(set(DF1.columns) - set(cols_18))
pd.merge(DF1[cols_to_use],DF2...), on = 'ID', how ='left')
```

If you want to keep the columns from both dataframes, the default suffixes are _x and _y. but you can override them like following

```
pd.merge(DF1,DF2...), on = 'ID', how ='left, suffixes = ["","_new"])
```

Now there will be 109 columns, but the main dataframe's column names stay intact. The columns from the DF2 have a suffix of "_new"

Comment: but this method will only get values from DF2 for those 18 columns, so rows where 'ID' column does not match, those rows will have NaNs in these 18 columns.

Comment: if we removed 18 columns from DF1 and we got [cols_to_use] , this would mean we got rid of rows information that unmatched with DF2 .  so technically I would need these rows in DF1 after merging based on a common value.

Comment: I am not able to understand the question exactly. can you probably provide an example of say DataFrames of size 2x2 and show what you want?