# How to replace multiple rows in a dataframe with rows from another dataframe based on column value/string?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 country lists and a year array as follows:

```
regions1 = ["Brazil", "Canada", "China", "Mexico", "USA"]
regions2 = ["Brazil", "China", "USA"]
years    = np.arange(1990,2031)
```

And 2 dataframes that look as follows, df1:

```
Index   Country   Source   1990   1991   ...   2030
0       Brazil    A        300    350          550
1       Canada    A        200    300          400
2       China     B        1000   1100         1300
3       Mexico    B        500    450          500
4       USA       C        650    800          1000
```

And df2:

```
Index   Country   Source   1990   1991   ...   2030
0       Canada    A        300    350          600
1       Mexico    B        550    670          800
2       USA       C        850    900          1500
```

I want to replace the values in the df1 columns 1990-2030 with the values in the df2 columns for the same countries. I have tried the .replace, .combine_first and.update methods but none of them work.
I then tried with:

```
df1.loc[df1.Country=='Canada',[str(z)for z in years]] = df2.loc[df2.Country=='Canada',[str(z)for z in years]]
```

which for some reason does not work. The only thing that has worked so far is:

```
df1.loc[1,[str(z)for z in years]] = df2.loc[0,[str(z)for z in years]]
```

This replaces all the values for Canada correctly while keeping everything else the same, which is what I want, however I need to do it manually for each country/index, which is not very elegant and not possible if the dataframes are large.

What would be a 'pythonic' way to replace all values for the common countries in df1 with the values from df2? I have looked for 2 days where I could but none of the proposed solutions work for all cases for me, only one at a time like the above.

Thank you!

Comment: I think the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045086/pandas-left-join-and-update-existing-column#30045284) will perfectly work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try merging both df's on `['Country','Source']` and then fill the NaN's of df2 with df1 then drop the columns of df2:

```
out=(df1.drop(columns='Index')
        .merge(df2.drop(columns='Index'),on=['Country','Source'],how='left',suffixes=('_x','')))
out=(out.fillna(out.filter(like='_x').rename(columns=lambda x:x.strip('_x')))
        .drop(out.filter(like='_x').columns,1))
```

output of `out`:

```
  Country Source    1990    1991    2030
0  Brazil      A   300.0   350.0   550.0
1  Canada      A   300.0   350.0   600.0
2   China      B  1000.0  1100.0  1300.0
3  Mexico      B   550.0   670.0   800.0
4     USA      C   850.0   900.0  1500.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) in the following way:

1. Set index on `Country` and the filter only the columns with 4-digit years:

```
df1a = df1.set_index('Country').filter(regex='\d{4}')
df2a = df2.set_index('Country').filter(regex='\d{4}')
```

2. Update `df1a` with `df2a` using `.update()`

```
df1a.update(df2a)
```

3. Restore the `Source` column of `df1` at the original column position:

```
df1_updated = df1a.reset_index()
df1_updated.insert(1, 'Source', df1['Source'])
```

**Result:**

```
print(df1_updated)

  Country Source    1990    1991    2030
0  Brazil      A   300.0   350.0   550.0
1  Canada      A   300.0   350.0   600.0
2   China      B  1000.0  1100.0  1300.0
3  Mexico      B   550.0   670.0   800.0
4     USA      C   850.0   900.0  1500.0
```