# pandas - Update only specific DataFrame column values based on a 'key' value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, updates

I have the two following DataFrames,

`stats`:

```
player_id   player_name   gp    ab   run   hit
    28920      S. Smith    1     2     1     3
    33351    T. Mancini    0     0     0     0
    30267     C. Gentry    0     0     0     0
    34885        H. Kim    1     0     0     0
    31988     J. Schoop    0     0     0     0
     5908    J.J. Hardy    1     3     0     0
```

& `game`:

```
player_id   player_name   gp    ab   run    hit
    28920      S. Smith    1     4     1      1
    33351    T. Mancini    1     1     0      1
    34885        H. Kim    1     1     2      0
    5908     J.J. Hardy    1     4     0      0
```

I want to update the statistics only for the players who've been active in the last game, based on the `player_id`, so that the final statistics DataFrame looks like this:

```
player_id   player_name   gp    ab   run   hit
    28920      S. Smith    2     6     2     4
    33351    T. Mancini    1     1     0     1
    30267     C. Gentry    0     0     0     0
    34885        H. Kim    2     1     2     0
    31988     J. Schoop    0     0     0     0
     5908    J.J. Hardy    2     7     0     0
```

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: What, what, the 2017 Orioles! Anyhow, it is not clear in the data given how you can tell who played in the most recent game. You imply that the player_id tells you who played in the most recent game, but I don't see how. Do you have a DataFrame for each game? Could you elaborate further?

Comment: Stats show the current team statistics and game is one specific game, hence game['gp'] = 1. Therefore, after game is added to stats, the news stats will update stats['gp'] by 1. This will give me the current statistics after they were udpate by 1 game. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with `set_index` and `update`

```
stats=stats.set_index(['player_id','player_name'])
game=game.set_index(['player_id','player_name'])
stats.update(game)
stats = stats.astype(int).reset_index()
stats
Out[452]: 
   player_id player_name  gp  ab  run  hit
0      28920     S.Smith   1   4    1    1
1      33351   T.Mancini   1   1    0    1
2      30267    C.Gentry   0   0    0    0
3      34885       H.Kim   1   1    2    0
4      31988    J.Schoop   0   0    0    0
5       5908   J.J.Hardy   1   4    0    0
```

Since you update your question using `add`

```
#stats=stats.set_index(['player_id','player_name'])
#game=game.set_index(['player_id','player_name'])
stats.add(game,fill_value=0).astype(int).reset_index()
Out[460]: 
   player_id player_name  gp  ab  run  hit
0       5908   J.J.Hardy   2   7    0    0
1      28920     S.Smith   2   6    2    4
2      30267    C.Gentry   0   0    0    0
3      31988    J.Schoop   0   0    0    0
4      33351   T.Mancini   1   1    0    1
5      34885       H.Kim   2   1    2    0
```

Comment: Doesn't this replace the values altogether though? I am looking to add the values together, not replace them entirely.

Comment: @michael0196 how about `stats.add(game,fill_value=0)`

Comment: At the end I recommend `stats = stats.astype(int).reset_index()`. Unfortunately, `update` has a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398216/unwanted-type-conversion-in-pandas-dataframe-update) which changes `int` to `float` due to internal use of `NaN`.